# Embeded jsp page in my vaadin view

Tags: java, vaadin

I want embeded jsp page in my vaadin view. Kindly let me know the steps to follow.

I have done the following steps :

1. Added my jsp page in vaadin view as follows.

   ```
   Embedded jsp = new Embedded();
   jsp.setType(Embedded.TYPE_BROWSER);
   jsp.setWidth("200px");
   jsp.setHeight("200px");
   jsp.setSource(new ExternalResource ("out.jsp"));
   ```

But I do not know how to include mapping in web.xml for this jsp.

Kindly explain me the steps like where i need to place jsp file , how to do mapping request

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I wonder if you are using Vaadin appropriately. The purpose of Vaadin is to provide the user-interface of your web app by building entirely in Java. So generally you should have no need to embed web views or web content.

## `BrowserFrame` widget

But on occasion, it may make sense to embed some non-Vaadin content. See the [`BrowserFrame`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/BrowserFrame.html) widget as described in [*The Book of Vaadin*](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-embedded.html). Available in Vaadin 7.0 and later.

## Portlet

If your Vaadin app is only a small part of a much bigger web site context, be aware that Vaadin is also built to function as a [Java Portlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Portlet_Specification).

[LifeRay](https://www.liferay.com) is a portlet environment commonly [used in conjunction with Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/liferay) for portlet-driven apps.

Comment: Thanks for ur suggetion @Basil Bourque

Answer (score 0):

Basil's answer could be valid if your JSP page it's in a separate servlet, no matter if outside of your own control (let's say a public webpage) or not (you can install it as a separate servlet in your own server). In both cases there wouldn't make a difference if it was a JSP page, a PHP or whatever -- in every usual case all you would get in either case is plain interpreted HTML. That said, the `BrowserFrame` approach could be the proper one, as it's the Vaadin equivalent to the "good ole" HTML `iframe`.

If you want to embed a JSP page or an **entire** JSP app you could do it by playing with Servlet Mapping and `webapp` folder. The only drawback is that your Vaadin app will need to be accessible from a new "path" instead of the root one Let's say you were accessing via `http://yourdomain.com/yourVaadinApp` -- now you'll need to define an /app -or similar- path, so your app will be accessible from `http://yourdomain.com/yourVaadinApp/app`. And you have to define it in your `@WebServlet` annotation in your main UI app class (it can be done via `web.xml`, too):

```
@WebServlet(value = {"/app/*", "/VAADIN/*"}, asyncSupported = true)
```

Next, you can put your JSP (or collection of JSP files) inside `yourAppProjectFolder/src/main/webapp` folder. That way, when deploying your app, your JSP will be accessible from the `base path/yourFile.jsp` (or simply base path if your file is the default document -depending on your server or your configuration, something like `index.jsp`-, that would be `http://yourdomain.com/yourVaadinApp/`), or a folder of your choice.

Unfortunately, to this moment I don't know a way of "excluding" the webapp folder content without mapping the Vaadin application base path to a "subpath".